# How do I multiply two columns based on a 3rd column

Tags: r

I'm looking to multiply 2 columns based on certain criteria.

I've tried IF/IFElse but probably haven't done them correctly.

```
BetData1 <- tibble(
 Date = c("18/04/19", "18/04/19", "18/04/19"),
 Nation = c("Austria","Spain","Colombia"),
 League = c("Regionalliga", "Tercera","Primera A"),
 Home = c("Stadl Paura", "Tamaraceite", "U.Magdalena"),
 Away = c("Vokermarkt", "San Fernando", "America de Cali"),
 Pick = c("Home Win", "Home Win", "Home Win"),
 Odds = c("1.28","1.49","2.22"),
 Stake = c("5","5","5"),
 Result = c("W","W","L"))
BetData1
```

The criteria I'm looking for is if 'Result' = W, then Stake*Odds, if 'Result' = L then Stake-Stake, and for it to go into a new column called 'Return'

Any help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

BetData1 %>% 
  mutate(Return = ifelse(Result == "W", as.numeric(Stake)*as.numeric(Odds), 0))
```

Comment: Sorry, just to add to this @J_F, can I nest ifelse's for this? How would I go about getting the profit and loss from similar code?